# Leveraging AWS Neptune Gremlin Client Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

We're looking to leverage the Neptune Gremlin client library to get load balancing and refreshes automatic.

There is a blog article here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/load-balance-graph-queries-using-the-amazon-neptune-gremlin-client/

This is also a repo containing the code here:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-gremlin-client

However, the artifacts aren't published anywhere. Is it still possible to do this? Ideally, we avoid vendoring the code into our codebase since we would then forefeit updates.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if those JAR files are available anywhere. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifacts for several of the tools in that repo can be found here.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/releases/tag/amazon-neptune-tools-1.2

Comment: Thanks Kelvin! Wasn't sure if you guys published them to a central repository like Maven Central or not, but we can throw them into our project.